# Trying to figure out why eslint-watch doesn't work with docker-compose correctly

Tags: docker-compose, eslint

I have been trying to get my front-end working on docker for the past day and I have narrowed down some irregular behaviour to eslint-watch and docker. I have recreated a minimal working [repo](https://github.com/ryannealmes/eslint-watch-bug-replica) of the bug I am experiencing.

It seems that linting is somehow staggered when using docker-compose (`docker-compose up` specifically, `docker-compose run` seems to work fine). Rather the last console log statements are staggered. I am not sure what it is, but from my reading the best interpretation I can give is that the log messages that should be printed out for the linting are for some reason not flushed out of the node message queue.

I have narrowed down the message printing to the eslint [watcher](https://github.com/rizowski/eslint-watch/blob/master/src/watcher.js#L54) file. If I add in more console logs at the end of this method it prints out the linting fine, but it staggers my logs (i.e. the last logs in execution). Funny thing is, if I save again it flushes the rest of the message queue i.e. the previous logs print out.

To replicate, download my repo, run `docker-compose up` and edit the test.js file and save. Watch the logs in your terminal for the linting. You will see what I mean.

I hope this is descriptive enough, it's a really strange bug and difficult to explain in a question.

Any ideas how I can actually figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. iterm of all things was the culprit. Really weird.

Anyway I was using iTerm2 3.0.9. It seems in iTerm2 3.0.12 (OS 10.8+) this bug is fixed.

https://github.com/rizowski/eslint-watch/issues/94#issuecomment-261287265